# Consistent layout of groups within subgroups in treemapifyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, treemap

I've got a three-level dataset, where the values of the intermediate categories are distinct to the largest categories, but where the (2) values of the smallest categories are consistent within each of the intermediate categories.

I'm using treemapifyr, and I'd like the layout to consistently have one of the smallest categories either on the left-hand side or on the top of the intermediate category. At the moment, these intermediate categories sometimes have horizontal splits, and at other times have vertical splits.

This reprex illustrates the issue:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(treemapifyr)

example_data <- 
  data.frame(Number = c(8.989663702,14.93294526,
                          5.727538109,11.47738226,5.962484342,5.528905863,
                          13.89280722,19.05866541,10.17157544,11.59719022,
                          17.93635842,2.034230053,13.38663681,8.729627328,
                          11.16785702,3.345153661,4.826922784,11.24138854),
                  Big = c("First","First","First",
                          "First","First","First","Second","Second",
                          "Second","Second","Third","Third","Third","Third",
                          "Third","Third","Third","Third"),
         Intermediate = c("A","A","B","B","C",
                          "C","D","D","E","E","F","F","G","G","H","H",
                          "I","I"),
                Small = c("Alpha","Beta","Alpha",
                          "Beta","Alpha","Beta","Alpha","Beta","Alpha",
                          "Beta","Alpha","Beta","Alpha","Beta","Alpha",
                          "Beta","Alpha","Beta")
   )
example_data %>% 
  group_by(Big, Intermediate) %>% 
  mutate(Fraction = 
           Number/sum(Number)) %>% 
  ggplot()+ 
  aes(area = Number,
      subgroup2 = Intermediate,
      subgroup = Big,
      group = Small) + 
  geom_treemap(aes(fill = Small)) +
  geom_treemap_subgroup2_border(colour = "gray50",
                                size = 2) +
  geom_treemap_subgroup_border(colour = "white") +
  geom_treemap_subgroup2_text(place = "centre") +
  geom_treemap_text(aes(label = round(Fraction, 2)))
```

[image: treemap containing a three-level dataset, with polygons in pink and blue]

If it's possible to have these configured so that the intermediate category (in this case, Intermediate) is always split side-by-side or top-to-bottom in the same order each time, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a `fixed` `layout` instead of the default `squarified` one. All elements should have the same layout, to ensure borders and text line up with the rest of the plot. I also chose to change the starting position from the default in the `bottomleft` to the `topleft`. If that doesn't look good with your real data, you can experiment with starting from any corner.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(treemapify)

layout = 'fixed'
start = 'topleft'

example_data %>% 
  group_by(Big, Intermediate) %>% 
  mutate(Fraction = 
           Number/sum(Number)) %>% 
  ggplot()+ 
  aes(area = Number,
      subgroup2 = Intermediate,
      subgroup = Big,
      group = Small) + 
  geom_treemap(aes(fill = Small),
               layout = layout,
               start = start) +
  geom_treemap_subgroup2_border(colour = "gray50",
                                size = 2,
                                layout = layout,
                                start = start) +
  geom_treemap_subgroup_border(colour = "white",
                               layout = layout,
                               start = start) +
  geom_treemap_subgroup2_text(place = "centre",
                              layout = layout,
                              start = start) +
  geom_treemap_text(aes(label = round(Fraction, 2)),
                    layout = layout,
                    start = start)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (You didn't add layout = and start = for geom_treemap_text, hence the odd locations of the numeric labels, but adding those has addressed it)

Comment: Good catch, thank you. I'll update the answer in case anyone stumbles across this.